# storing string addition in a variable for calculator function

Tags: javascript, variables, operators, addition

I am trying to do a Calculator in JavaScript, so I started with addition operation.

I tried to convert addition operator into a string to add into a variable so that I can add the values from function. I found out it is not possible is there any better way to solve this issue.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/akashdikkaram/pen/wywEWv)

```js
var store = '';
var totalvalue;


function one() {
  store += "1";
  totalvalue = Number(store);
  console.log(totalvalue);
  document.querySelector('.exit').textContent = store;
}


function two() {
  store += "2";
  totalvalue = Number(store)
  console.log(totalvalue);
  document.querySelector('.exit').textContent = store;
}


function add()
{
  store = '+';
  totalvalue = parseInt(store);
  //THIS IS WHERE ITS NOT WORKING I CAME TO KNOW THAT I CANT STORE A OPERATOR
  console.log(totalvalue);
  document.querySelector('.exit').textContent = store;
}

function equalsto() {
  console.log(totalvalue);
  document.querySelector('.total').textContent = totalvalue;
}
```

```html
<button class="addition" onclick="add()">+</button><br>
<button class="one" onclick="one()">1</button><br>
<button class="two" onclick="two()">2</button><br>
<button class="output" onclick="equalsto()">=</button>

<p class="exit"></p>
<h1 class="total">total</h1>
```

Comment: Well, yes, `parseInt` does not do arithmetic.

Comment: @Bergi anyother way ???

Comment: You could build on of these good old stack-based [RPN calculators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), that should be rather simple. Other than that, you will need to bite the bullet and implement  a parse for arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it all wrong , in store variable , you should add up the string of all the commands and numbers pressed and use eval to get result whereas you are only replacing store vaiable with current clicked value opreraton like add
You shoudl first add + sign to store and then parse it:

```
function add()

{

    store+ = '+';

    totalvalue = parseInt(store);


    console.log(totalvalue);
    document.querySelector('.exit').textContent = store;


}
```

A better way would be to design the buttons and get their text in complete string to a final variable.To evaluate result on '=' , you can just use

```
ans=eval(string_of_variable)
```

```css
#e {
  background-color: red;
}

button:nth-child(4n+2) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<button>6</button>
<button>7</button>
<button>8</button>
<button>9</button>
<button>0</button>
<button>+</button>
<button>-</button>
<button>/</button>
<button>*</button>
<p id="e">= (Click to evaluate)</p>
<br>
<p id="ex"></p>
<script>
  var main = "";
  $("button").click(function() {
    main += ($(this)[0].innerText);
    $("#ex")[0].innerText = main;
  });
  $("#e").click(function() {
    alert("Answer of " + main + " is: " + eval(main));
    main = "";
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: hi abhishek thx for this solution but i am learning js. so it would be great if i can do anyother way with pureJS

Comment: why not , you can use document.querySelector /document.getElementById
Please upvote if this helped thanks